# how to pass datatable in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have two datatable
dt1 and dt2

and my stored procedure are as follows

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Sp_ShowAllEmpLeaveSummary]
@TableName1 nvarchar(128) ,
@TableName2 nvarchar(128)
as
begin

DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',' + name + '', '' + name + '') FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    'CAST(ISNULL('+@TableName1 +'.' + name + ',0) AS VARCHAR) + ''/'' + CAST('+@TableName2 +'.' + name + ' AS VARCHAR) AS ' + name + ' ' AS name 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE NAME LIKE '%leave%' 
AND object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE name IN (''+@TableName1 +'', ''+@TableName2 +''))) LeaveColumns

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = N'
SELECT 
'+@TableName1 +'.empid, 
'+@TableName2 +'.empname, ' + @Columns + ' 
FROM dt1 
INNER JOIN '+@TableName2 +' ON '+@TableName1 +'.empid='+@TableName2 +'.empid'    


EXECUTE(@SQL)
end
```

and in Ui I pass the parameter like this

```
 cmd4.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TableName1", SqlDbType.Structured)).Value = dt1;
   cmd4.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TableName2", SqlDbType.Structured)).Value = dt2;
```

but its showing error **Operand type clash: table type is incompatible with    nvarchar(128)**. so can i solve this problem

Thanks

Comment: Its better to convert datatable to XML string and pass it to Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a table, you have to define the table as a custom type, and pass that into the procedure.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

But it looks like you just want to pass the name.

So the C# type should be `SqlDbType.NVarChar`

Additionally, you should sanitise your inputs to prevent SQL injection, and not prefix your stored procedure with `sp_`

Comment: but in my datattable coloumns are not fix so how can I create a custom table?   Thanks

Comment: I don't know. What on earth are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I have completely understood your SP and how you are calling it but as you are constructing an SQL command in your SP you must pass the name of the datatable also as a string and put it into the command like this

```
ALTER procedure empl
 @tb1 nvarchar(128) ,
 @tb2 nvarchar(128) 
as
BEGIN
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',' + name + '', '' + name + '') FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    'CAST(ISNULL('+@tb1 +'.' + name + ',0) AS VARCHAR) + ''/'' + CAST('
                  +@tb2 +'.' + name + ' AS VARCHAR) AS ' + name + ' ' AS name 
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE NAME LIKE '%leave%' 
    AND object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables 
                      WHERE name IN (@tb1,@tb2))
) LeaveColumns

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = N'
SELECT 
'+@tb1 +'.empid, 
'+@tb2 +'.empname, ' + @Columns + ' 
FROM '+@tb1+'
INNER JOIN '+@tb2 +' ON '+@tb1 +'.empid='+@tb2 +'.empid'    

-- SELECT @SQL; -- for debug purposes
EXECUTE(@SQL)
END
```

Do you mean `dt1` to be `@tb1` in the SP ?!?
(I shortened the variable names for better readability)